# While debugging a CLR Stored Procedure VS2008 is giving error like 'cancelled by user'

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, debugging, clr

please any one help me

while debugging a CLR sp am getting  error like "cancelled by user"

i think i need to enable something?

Answer (score 0):

See [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/0d96bb74-295e-4ed0-a458-32d37bf02848) and [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2013735) for various ideas.

In my case (Windows XP, local debugging) it mysteriously helped to turn off "Deploy code" option in the VS project.

P.S. To help Google find it: actual error is (misspelled) "canceled by user".